# NullPointerException occurs when spring-cloud-sleuth(boot) integration with spring-integration

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-integration-amqp

I am using spring-amqp via spring-integration.
By the way, when using spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin, the following error occurred.

spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:1.0.9
spring-integration-core:4.2.9
spring-amqp:1.5.6

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:135)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:71)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1278)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.access$2400(RabbitTemplate.java:127)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$10.doWithRetry(RabbitTemplate.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:276)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:172)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceiveWithTemporary(RabbitTemplate.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.sendAndReceive(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:367)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:318)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:79)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:412)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:386)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:458)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:418)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.sendToRabbit(Unknown Source)
    at com.daumkakao.techasset.qostore.nest.handler.netty.MagpiePutHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(MagpiePutHttpRequestHandler.java:84)
    at com.daumkakao.techasset.qostore.nest.handler.netty.MagpiePutHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(MagpiePutHttpRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.daumkakao.techasset.qostore.nest.handler.netty.AbstractQostoreHttpRequestHandler.handle(AbstractQostoreHttpRequestHandler.java:39)
    at com.daumkakao.techasset.qostore.nest.handler.netty.AbstractQostoreHttpRequestHandler.handle(AbstractQostoreHttpRequestHandler.java:13)
    at com.daumkakao.techasset.qostore.nest.handler.netty.NestHttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(NestHttpRequestHandler.java:66)
    at com.daumkakao.techasset.qostore.nest.handler.netty.NestHttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(NestHttpRequestHandler.java:32)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: 1.0.x branch is no longer maintained. Can you please check Camden or Dalston releases if the problem is still there?

Comment: Looks like it is the same old issue with the CGLib proxying. This time we have problem with the `final createConnection()` in the `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory`. Not sure though why this one is proxied as well...